Add/parent physicsless sprite to matterjs vertexbody such that it moves with the body. PhaserJS using MatterJS

const poly1 = this.add.polygon(200, 200, Ployploy, 0x0000ff, 0.2);
ThisPlayer = this.matter.add.gameObject(poly1, { shape: { type: 'fromVerts', verts: Ployploy, flagInternal: true } });

//add this sprite to a container with the above object...Atleast thats what Im hoping to do.
ThisPlayer.testSprite = this.add.sprite(200,200, '');

What I have here is a snippet of code that given a list of vertices will create a physics body from them. After that what Im wanting to do is add a sprite to  that body. In my full code I have a 2d array that defines where different sprites should be places onto that vertex body. Sadly Im failing to get just one to stick onto it.  I could create a separate container with the tilemap / sprites and update its position constantly in the update loop, but I feel like there has to be some way to just stick these onto the physics object directly. Ive attached an image which shows the sprite which remains static despite the physics body having moved.
Ive looked online for examples of what Ive described above but cant seem to find any of my same situation. Im assume that because its obscure chatGPT cant resolve the issue either and hallucinates using ThisPlayer.add(sprite) or ThisPlayer+= Sprite. Mentioned above Ive got a few other solutions that I know will work but seem jank and Id like to do things right if possible.

Honestly this trend of "Coding" with ChatGPT and let other fix janky code is the downfall of programming. Since phaser has tones of examples, even some on matterjs check out this link and if not you might have to check out matterjs examples and find out how to merge them.

Chatgpt only serves as an additional tool when I've already searched though the documentation already myself. Ive even asked in other phaser communities but the question just went ignored( I dont fault anyone else for this of course) It's the same sort of thing as when I talk to my friends or family about the issue I'm facing with codde. A rubber ducky method of finding a solution since i have to describe my issue in full. Sadly I've already looked though those examples. Honestly I'm just surprised there's no built in "lock this item to this item" function.  For now I'm using a separate contai

Is your question solved? Or do you need some more help?

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but if I would have to guess you are looking for something like this (look at running demo, below). No Container needed. Some comments in the code, explains what it does.
But basically you create a sprite, and add a physicbody with  this.matter.add.gameObject(sprite, { shape: { type: 'fromVerts', verts: somePolygon, flagInternal: true } }); where you add the vertices as parameter, for the shape you need.
Small working demo:


    document.body.style = 'margin:0;';
    var config = {
        width: 536,
        height: 183,
        physics: {
            default: 'matter',
            matter: {
                debug: {
                    renderFill: false,
                    showInternalEdges: true,
                    showConvexHulls: true
                }
            }
        },
        scene: {
            preload,
            create
        },
    };

    function preload() {
        // from an official demo
        this.load.spritesheet('brawler', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 });
    }

    function create() {
        this.add.text(10, 10, 'Matter Demo')
            .setScale(1.5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({ fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial' });

        this.matter.world.setBounds().disableGravity();

        // Animation to make it nicer
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'kick',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [10, 11, 12, 13, 10] }),
            frameRate: 8,
            repeat: -1,
            repeatDelay: 2000
        });


        const somePolygon = '100 50 75 50 100 80 25 100 5 50 25 0';

        // Create sprite
        const sprite = this.add.sprite(80, 80, 'brawler').setScale(2).play('kick');

        // create matter object
        this.matter.add.gameObject(sprite, { shape: { type: 'fromVerts', verts: somePolygon, flagInternal: true } });

        sprite.setVelocity(1, 1);
        sprite.setAngularVelocity(0.01);
        sprite.setBounce(1);
        sprite.setFriction(0, 0, 0);
    }

    new Phaser.Game(config);
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>



Basically combining like in this example

Tipp: Your question don't have to be so verbose, if you follow the SO how to ask guide, and might result in faster and better answers. And if you provide a working MRE, misunderstanding can be prevented.

